# Не моу построить сравнительную (двойную) гистограмму из таблицы Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Вот таблица из датафрейма:

|  | Баллы_groups | Кол-во Контракт | Кол-во Ушедшие |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 350+ | 108 | 275 |
| 2 | 300-350 | 725 | 1718 |
| 3 | 250-300 | 885 | 3170 |
| 4 | 200-250 | 2121 | 10890 |
| 5 | 150-200 | 3120 | 7925 |
| 6 | 100-150 | 653 | 1318 |
| 7 | 50-100 | 101 | 247 |
| 8 | 0-50 | 45 | 137 |

хотелось бы из неё получить подобное:

[image: Гистограмма]

но что бы столбцы соответствовали оси 'x', которая строилась из колонки 'Баллы_groups'
примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перепробовал уже кучу вариантов - но получить не смог.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можете в вопросе привести код последнего испробованного варианта?

Comment: df.plot(kind ='hist')
plt.xlabel('Points_groups')
plt.ylabel("Number Of Students");

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Баллы_groups': ['350+', '300-350', '250-300', '200-250', '150-200', '100-150', '50-100', '0-50'],
                   'Кол-во Контракт': [108, 725, 885, 2121, 3120, 653, 101, 45],
                   'Кол-во Ушедшие': [275, 1718, 3170, 10890, 7925, 1318, 247, 137]})
df.plot(x='Баллы_groups', y=['Кол-во Контракт', 'Кол-во Ушедшие'], kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, огромное. 
Почему-то на такое очевидное и простое решение я не натыкался.

А как ещё можно доходчиво через графики визуализировать сравниваемую информацию? 
(Я совсем начинающий...)

Comment: https://datayoga.ru/vizcards

Comment: Спасибо. А как диаграмму повернуть на 90 градусов, что ось х была вертикальная?

Comment: аргумент `kind='barh'`

Comment: И как этот вариант  сравнительной (двойной) гистограммы построить через Seaborn? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Через `seaborn` я только через преобразование датасета сумел, наверняка можно как-то проще. Спасибо Алексей Р за подготовку данных, и вообще отличный ответ.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Баллы_groups': ['350+', '300-350', '250-300', '200-250', '150-200', '100-150', '50-100', '0-50'],
                   'Кол-во Контракт': [108, 725, 885, 2121, 3120, 653, 101, 45],
                   'Кол-во Ушедшие': [275, 1718, 3170, 10890, 7925, 1318, 247, 137]})

df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['Баллы_groups'], value_vars=['Кол-во Контракт', 'Кол-во Ушедшие'])
sns.barplot(x='Баллы_groups', y='value', data=df1, hue='variable')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь и seaborn в моём арсенале.